# How do I structure my while-loop control flow?

Tags: c, while-loop

If a 9-digit number is entered as a scanf in while, the while must be repeated repeatedly, and if a 0 is entered, the while must be exited.

I have compiled the source below, but the break doesn't seem to work.

Variable types are a prerequisite for the problem, so I cannot correct them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int aa[10];
    char bb[8];

    while (1) {
        printf("9 number or 0: ");
        scanf("%d", &aa);
        if (aa == 0)
            break;

        printf("7 number : ");
        scanf("%s", bb);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're studying C, why the `C++` tag?

Comment: You declared `int aa[10];`. Hence, `aa` is an array. Checking `aa == 0` checks effectively if the address of `aa` is 0 what it is never. (That's in C as well as C++.)

Comment: first of all you use `c++` in the `title` and in  `tag` so i assuming you mean you're studying `C++` and not C . second for me `while(1)` is bad idea i will advise you to create a flag then `if(aa==0)` change the flag .

Comment: This question is clearly about C, not C++.

Comment: @dt170 There is nothing wrong with `while (1)` as it isn't with `for (;;)`. To place a loop condition in the middle of its body, it's IMHO usual.

Comment: @Scheff you'd usually do `while(true)` instead of `while(1)`, no? I find it slightly more readable.

Comment: @Ayxan It's not yet clear whether this is about C or C++. Even in C++, there is nothing wrong with `while (1)`. However, this was about the necessity to add a condition with flag...

Comment: @Scheff Didn't say its bad thing, I meant it is a bad idea since its infinite loop and may cause bugs. I try to avoid using `while(1)` if it really isn't necessary . again that is my perception

Comment: @dt170 Beside of maintainability or readability. I would feel unconvenient to first set a flag (knowing that means to exit the loop) and then to check that flag again (in next iteration) to exit it finally. A simple `break` can achieve the effect as well (like OP intended). So, why to buy some extra effort?

Comment: That's a bit unclear: _If a 9-digit number is entered as a scanf in while, the while must be repeated repeatedly, and if a 0 is entered, the while must be exited._ What if an 8-digit number is entered? What about a 10-digit number? Please, elaborate this a bit.

Comment: @Ayxan I personally prefer `for (;;)` for infinite loops or loops with in-body-bailout. The former, I need very rarely. (Until now, none of my applications was really dedicated to run forever.) For the latter case, it's my personal idiom/eye-catcher to not to forget the conditional bail-out in the body. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This declares an array of ten `int`s, not *one* `int` with 9 digits:

```
int aa[10];
```

You should remove the array part:

```
int aa;
```

Also check that your `scanf`s are successful. Example:

```
if(scanf("%d", &aa) != 1) break;
```

Comment: That was worth my upvote for mentioning as well that I/O should be checked for success always. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your integer has a problem. When you put the brackets next to the variable name, you created an integer array with 10 elements.

You should change

```
int aa[10];
```

to

```
int aa;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `aa` is an array. `if (aa == 0)` isn't going to work in the way you are doing it.

You need something like this.

```
int main() {
  //...

  while (1) {
    int num;
    printf("9 number or 0: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    if (num == 0) break;

    aa[count] = num;
    count++;

    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said that you can't change variable types you should check if `aa[0] == 0`, when you used an array and scaned it like you did `scanf("%d", &aa);`, you save the number to the first place (index 0) in the array (usually you do something like `scanf("%d", &aa[0]);`), and in your if statement when you don't put  `aa[0] == 0` but just `aa == 0` you are checking the address of `aa` (not the value on the address) which is just a random number.